# Finding Maximum of the function using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Use the Lagrange Multipliers to find the maximum value of the function $f(x,y,z)= x+2y+3z$ on the curve of intersection of the plane $x-y+z=1$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2-1=0$

I wrote $x-y+z-1 = x^2+y^2-1 = g(x,y,z)$ is it true way? if im able to find 1 constraint here, I might solve the system.

really thanks.

Comment: Did you learn how to use Lagrange Multipliers with two constraints?

Comment: Lagrange multipier with multiple constraints: The extrema for f(x,y,z) under the constraints g(x,y,z)=0 and h(x,y,z)=0 satisfies $\nabla f=c_1 \nabla g+c_2 \nabla h$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$

Comment: I really didn't learn just by watching YouTube channels

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimize $$f(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z$$
You have two constraints
$$g(x,y,z)=x-y+z-1=0$$
and
$$h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-1=0$$
So you will minimize $h(x,y,z)-\lambda g(x,y,z)-\mu h(x,y,z)$:
$$\frac d{dx}[x+2y+3z-\lambda(x-y+z-1)-\mu(x^2+y^2-1)]=0\\
\frac d{dy}[x+2y+3z-\lambda(x-y+z-1)-\mu(x^2+y^2-1)]=0\\
\frac d{dz}[x+2y+3z-\lambda(x-y+z-1)-\mu(x^2+y^2-1)]=0$$

Together with the equations for your two constraints, you have 5 equations with 5 unknowns ($x, y, z, \lambda, \mu$).

Comment: Thanks your help. Dont I need to intersect cylinder and plane to make 1 constraint? I

Comment: No. You need to use two constraints. Writing the 1D curve in 3D space will make things more complicated

Comment: thanks again. the partial derivative of x^2+y^2-1 with respect to z is 0. I found X,y and lamda. to find z , can I use any constraint by putting X and y?

Comment: You probably want to use the plane, since the cylinder does not depend on $z$.

Answer (score 0):

In any case there are *three* primary variables and *two* constraints. Therefore the feasible set is a curve, namely the ellipse $\gamma$ obtained by intersecting the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ with the plane $z=1-x+y$. The following is a parametrization of $\gamma$:
$$t\mapsto \gamma(t):= (\cos t,\>\sin t,\>1-\cos t+\sin t)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
In order to find the maximum of $f$ on $\gamma$ it is sufficient to consider the pullback
$$\hat f(t):=f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)=\cos t+2\sin t+3(1-\cos t+\sin t)=3-2\cos t+5\sin t\ .$$
The maximum of $\hat f$ for real $t$ is given by
$$3+\sqrt{2^2+5^2}=3+\sqrt{29}\ ,$$
since we all know that the maximum of $\ a\cos t+b\sin t\ $ is $\ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.